# How to concatinate string with star character Ansible?

Tags: regex, join, ansible, supervisord

I have a list of paths stored in **files_path** variable.
This is a task where I am trying to concatenate paths from variable and adding the rest of the path using join.

```
- name: Changing supervisor files path
  replace:
    path: /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
    regexp: 'files(.*)'
    replace: 'files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf {{ supervisor_files_path | join(' ')/shared/supervisor/*.conf }}
  notify: restart supervisor
  when: files_path is defined
```

The error I get:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '*'. String: files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf {{ files_path | join(' ')/shared/supervisor/*.conf }}"}
```

The issue is with the second star in code here: `/shared/supervisor/*.conf`

I was trying to escape using `\*` or `[*]`, but getting the same error.

How should I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting `{{ }}` around it so it becomes `{{ /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf }}`. Also don't forget to put `" "` at the beginning and end of the line.